# apache httpclient use https proxy: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, ssl, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

i'm trying to use one of the big list of free https-proxy-servers on hidemyass.com (https://hidemyass.com/proxy-list/search-225434) with apache httpclient 4.1. i've now tried nearly all of them, but i always get **javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated**
so i googled and found out that no server has peer certificates, for example:

```
> openssl s_client -tls1 -showcerts -connect 109.75.178.230:3128  
CONNECTED(00000003)
139856907785896:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:s3_pkt.c:337:

no peer certificate available

No client certificate CA names sent

SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 7 bytes

New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1393183549
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

when i tried to switch to http on the same port it works, but in the proxy-list on hidemyass the type is https. so i don't know what to do now... please help.

if you need to have a look at my code: http://paste.debian.net/83674/

Answer (score 0):

So if you are ok you can trust all certificates as below

```
final TrustStrategy trustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {

        @Override
        public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
            return true;
        }
    };
    SSLContext sslcontext = null;
    try {
        sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, trustStrategy).build();
    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
```

Then create your HTTPClient using

```
httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
```

This will make sure that certificates for all the https calls are trusted
But ensure that you only call trusted sites only